# perror equivalent function in python

Tags: python, try-catch

I'm using try except block in python, while the try block fails , how to print meaningful error message. I'm looking for something like perror() in C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> try:
...     0/0
... except Exception,e:
...     print e.message
...
integer division or modulo by zero
```

or in Python 2.6 and above, `e.args`, because of `BaseException.message has been deprecated`

```
>>> try:
...     0/0
... except Exception,e:
...     print e.args
...
('integer division or modulo by zero',)
```

Comment: For Python 3, I seem to need something like `except Exception as e:` and then `print(e)`

Answer (score -3):

```
try:
   pass
except Exception, err:
   print err
```